# Python. Playsound "TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance, bytes found"

Tags: python

I've working about small script that must play 1 of my sounds. It's about 1,5 sec.

```
import playsound

mp3_sound = "audio.mp3"
playsound.playsound(mp3_sound)
```

And it gives this error:

```
"TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance, bytes found"
```

Help, pls.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your file is not in your run time folder. I would run the following code to verify you are providing the correct file path.

```
# one of many ways 
import os.path
os.path.exists(path_to_file)
```

Comment: It's a rely good advice, but I've copied the path from the Explorer. And I ran your code and it showed me the same path.

Comment: Looks like that is not the problem. I do not have any experience with this library but I might have time to look more into it later today.